# Generate different bell curves in php with small data

Tags: php, function, normal-distribution

I would like to be able to generate these bellcurves from very little data:

[image: bell cuves]

I'm looking for a function in php that would give me the data generated by these bell curves. I don't know yet what I'm going to use to display them, but I need the data first.

I'm not very good at math, I've tried creating some normal distribution, but there isn't an easy way to say: "I want a thin bell curve" or "I want a large one".

Maybe using the arguments that are on top of the right side of the picture above might be cool.

Would someone know how I can reproduce the datapoints of these graphs in PHP ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could look up the formula of the [normal distribution's probability density on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

A PHP implementation of this function would look like this:

```
function normal($x, $mu, $sigma) {
    return exp(-0.5 * ($x - $mu) * ($x - $mu) / ($sigma*$sigma))
        / ($sigma * sqrt(2.0 * M_PI));
}
```

This function will give you the value of the bell curves you posted.
I really suggest you read the Wikipedia article on the function, but to put it simply, `$mu` marks the position of the central peak of the bell curve and `$sigma` determines its width (a larger value for `$sigma` means a broader distribution).

Comment: took me some time to understand it but thank you! works well!

Comment: When I input this: $x = 0, $mu = 0, $sigma = 0.2 (blue curb), it gives me 1.99. which is different from the image above (taken from wikipedia). Is there something wrong ? is the wikipedia image wrong ? or is it the function ?

Comment: No, about 1.99 is correct. My guess is that the images just try to illustrate the distributions (their shape for different values of `$sigma`), not provide accurate values. Also take a look at this page: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=normal+distribution%2C+mu%3D0%2C+sigma%3D0.2